# Use custom Manifest file and permission in Unity?

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine

Im currently trying to program a little game for android with Unity3D. Because I want a visible status bar, I modified the AndroidManifest in the Project Folder (C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\ProjectName\Temp\StagingArea) like this :

```
<application android:theme="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
```

But everytime i generate the APK, unity changes the Android Manifest to this :

```
<application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
```

Unity3D does change my modified Manifests everytime?

Comment: What is the directory of the file you modified?

Comment: @Programmer It was somewhere in the Unity Projects folder which is located in the Documents. I used the search bar and just modified it ...

Comment: I am sorry. It doesn't work like that. Find it again then find the directory.  Update your answer with that.

Comment: @Programmer found the correct folder and updated my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are modifying the wrong `AndroidManifest` file. That `AndroidManifest` from `<ProjectName>\Temp\StagingArea` you are modifying is generated by unity each time you build your project.

To use a custom `AndroidManifest` file, you have to put your custom `AndroidManifest` file at `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`.

1.Go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk`, Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`

2.Open the copied Manifest file from `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`  and add your manifest.

In your particular case, add `<application android:theme="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">` to it. Save, Build and Run.

Unity will now use that `AndroidManifest` file. If you get crash or any other problem, then Unity does not want you to change that.

Comment: For Step 1 you can simply check ProjectSettings>Player>PublishingSettings>CustomMainManifest

Answer (score 15):

Starting with Unity 2018 you should implement the `IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject` [interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Android.IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject.html) which will allow you to edit the android manifest after Unity produces it. In the code below I have added methods to set the microphone permission, set hardware acceleration, and set your application theme ( replace `SetMicrophonePermission()` to your preferred method, which is called when Unity calls `OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject()`).

Add the following code to `Assets/Editor/ModifyUnityAndroidAppManifestSample.cs`

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEditor.Android;

public class ModifyUnityAndroidAppManifestSample : IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject
{

    public void OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject(string basePath)
    {
        // If needed, add condition checks on whether you need to run the modification routine.
        // For example, specific configuration/app options enabled

        var androidManifest = new AndroidManifest(GetManifestPath(basePath));

        androidManifest.SetMicrophonePermission();

        // Add your XML manipulation routines

        androidManifest.Save();
    }

    public int callbackOrder { get { return 1; } }

    private string _manifestFilePath;

    private string GetManifestPath(string basePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_manifestFilePath))
        {
            var pathBuilder = new StringBuilder(basePath);
            pathBuilder.Append(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Append("src");
            pathBuilder.Append(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Append("main");
            pathBuilder.Append(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Append("AndroidManifest.xml");
            _manifestFilePath = pathBuilder.ToString();
        }
        return _manifestFilePath;
    }
}


internal class AndroidXmlDocument : XmlDocument
{
    private string m_Path;
    protected XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr;
    public readonly string AndroidXmlNamespace = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    public AndroidXmlDocument(string path)
    {
        m_Path = path;
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(m_Path))
        {
            reader.Read();
            Load(reader);
        }
        nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("android", AndroidXmlNamespace);
    }

    public string Save()
    {
        return SaveAs(m_Path);
    }

    public string SaveAs(string path)
    {
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(path, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            Save(writer);
        }
        return path;
    }
}


internal class AndroidManifest : AndroidXmlDocument
{
    private readonly XmlElement ApplicationElement;

    public AndroidManifest(string path) : base(path)
    {
        ApplicationElement = SelectSingleNode("/manifest/application") as XmlElement;
    }

    private XmlAttribute CreateAndroidAttribute(string key, string value)
    {
        XmlAttribute attr = CreateAttribute("android", key, AndroidXmlNamespace);
        attr.Value = value;
        return attr;
    }

    internal XmlNode GetActivityWithLaunchIntent()
    {
        return SelectSingleNode("/manifest/application/activity[intent-filter/action/@android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN' and " +
                "intent-filter/category/@android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER']", nsMgr);
    }

    internal void SetApplicationTheme(string appTheme)
    {
        ApplicationElement.Attributes.Append(CreateAndroidAttribute("theme", appTheme));
    }

    internal void SetStartingActivityName(string activityName)
    {
        GetActivityWithLaunchIntent().Attributes.Append(CreateAndroidAttribute("name", activityName));
    }


    internal void SetHardwareAcceleration()
    {
        GetActivityWithLaunchIntent().Attributes.Append(CreateAndroidAttribute("hardwareAccelerated", "true"));
    }

    internal void SetMicrophonePermission()
    {
        var manifest = SelectSingleNode("/manifest");
        XmlElement child = CreateElement("uses-permission");
        manifest.AppendChild(child);
        XmlAttribute newAttribute = CreateAndroidAttribute("name", "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO");
        child.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a library that wraps around the code in this answer (in a limited manner): https://github.com/starikcetin/Eflatun.AndroidManifestHook

Comment: i meant my comment below to the main question to actually be a reply to this answer. Thanks for your code.

Answer (score 0):

for Unity runtime permissions, i wrote this function to add the skip permissions dialog (like https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html)

e.g

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
```

Here's the code:

```
internal void SetSkipPermissionsDialog()
{
    var manifest = SelectSingleNode("/manifest");
    var application = manifest.SelectSingleNode("application");
    XmlElement child = CreateElement("meta-data");
    application.AppendChild(child);
    XmlAttribute newAttribute = CreateAndroidAttribute("name", "unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog");
    child.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
    newAttribute = CreateAndroidAttribute("value", "true");
    child.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom AndroidManifest file,
Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file from `<ProjectName>\Temp\StagingArea`
and put it on the Android folder `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android`. Create the Plugins and Android folder if not present in the project directory.