# Downloading Unity .obb content via Android app

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, apk

I am trying to make a apk with .obb files, alpha on the store, however when trying to download the .obb it doesnt extract correctly or doesnt load all of the content I am not sure, any help would be appreciated.

its an Android structured app, with a assets folder coming from Unity, (which is the .obb file im making).

I have used the Downloader, License and Zip libraries Google recommends.

The two scenarios I am currently stuck at is:

**[Scenario 1]**

Using Unity to make a .obb file   [image]

The file contents from the .obb Unity generated for me:
[image]

The application downloads the .obb files correctly, but once i try and launch anything Unity related in the app, it searches for files Unity didnt add to the .obb file and breaks.

**[Scenario 2]**

I just made my own zip file of the assets folder containing alot more content:[image]

gave it the correct naming convention

> main.versionCode.packageName.obb

The apk downloads correctly and starts downloading the .obb file, but fails on 99% with no logs.

Has anyone come across this issue? or maybe can point out what I am doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019

Comment: Hi Brendan, this is one of the guides i followed, everything works up until the actual download from the play store which just fails with no output, or when i use Unity to make the obb file, Unity doesnt include some files need by the app

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: Hi, 5.5.1, however I wont be able to upgrade due to structural changes that will need to be made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Unity *5.5.1* and this is a [bug](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0).

Quate from Unity 5.6 release note.

> - Android: Fixed reading assets from OBB (ApplicationPath). (893913)

You do have to download *Unity 5.6* or above in order to fix this problem. I don't think there is another way to fix this without updating.

Other things I recommend you try before updating:

**1**.From the Build Settings, change the **Write Permission** from *Internal* to *External (SDCard)*

**2**.Explicitly add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the  AndroidManifest file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293396/3785314) post describes how to use custom AndroidManifest to your game.

**3**.Use Unity's free [Google Play OBB Downloader](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/3189) plugin to download the OBB data.

I think that the problem is loading the file so if **#1** and **#2** does not work, you should definitely update to *5.6* to get the version of Unity that fixed this problem..

Comment: thanx for the help I will mark as answered, but I made some progress in scenario 2, however I am not sure how to extract the obb file or if I need todo it manually? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934743/how-to-extract-obb-file-in-android-to-the-assets-directory

Comment: I will comment on your other question