# How to extract .obb file in android to the assets directory?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, apk

I am using libraries provided by the android sdk for apk expansion file to download the obb file, however I am not sure how to extract these files to the correct directory or if it is even possible?

The .obb file downloads correctly, and I can read the entire directory, however once I try and use any of the resources inside the zipped assets folder it doesnt find it. I have followed this guide (which is basically the same everywhere: http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.co.za/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html ) But I cant find where (or if its even necessary) to manually extract the .obb file? 
When the obb file is downloaded, it copies the entire .obb file to the /data directory, instead of extracting all the content.

If someone could just point me in the right direction, or explain to me what I am doing wrong it would help alot.

[image]

Structure of .obb file
If I understand correctly the APKExpansionSupport is used to work with files inside the .obb file directory? But how do I extract the assets folders contents to my projects assets folder?

Thanx!

Comment: Once you download the obb file, isn't it suppose to work without extraction?

Comment: thats what I thought? but it doesnt, the file downloads and validates correctly, but the entire obb file gets copied to the data directory?

Comment: is it not suppose to download into the .obb directory, and automatically extract into the data directory, and my code can just use it normally as if I didnt remove the assets folder before making a build?

Comment: To me, it looks like it is supposed to. How and where are you downloading this from?

Comment: its a closed alpha release,  apk and .obb file I published to the store, I have tried to manually copy some of the Unity.dll files over into a new directory when launching from android studio (instead of using the apk from store) and the app got further, but the moment I try and use any resources thats inside the .obb, it doesnt find it

Comment: When you say store, you mean Google Play? If so then you should use Google play to host the obb file. I believe that it will down int the right place.

Comment: yes the google play store, the obb file I made myself so I am not sure if its somehow corrupted ?

Comment: Use Unity to make the obb file instead of by yourself...

Comment: the thing is just, when i unzip the obb file i make manually, it works and everything is there

Comment: I am confused. Can you explain how you unzip it manually. Where do you do it from? On your computer? On the Android? Where do you unzip it into?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144053/discussion-between-user2042227-and-programmer).