# How to get native back button for android in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I don't want to use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)` to call back button, because in gradle build, The function has been done in unity, but then unity minimizes the application as well, I only want to get:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

inside unity. because I don't want to minimize the game.

Comment: This question is confusing. You want to detect when Android button is pressed from Java side?

Comment: in gradle build, unity call an extra function for minimizing game when I use Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape).

Comment: @Programmer its very important to me...

Comment: How do you you know if Unity is calling a function when you use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)`? I know you need `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)` but what happens if you don't use `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)`?

Comment: @Programmer because before i build with gradle, it works fine. and after that when in UnityPlayerActivity.java,  '@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }' calls, it minimized game.

Comment: I really want to help you but don't understand the source of your issue. You blamed the problem on `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)` but now you talking about `boolean onKeyDown`. These are not the-same and I don't know what to tell you

Comment: @Programmer Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) works in unity, but when i build it with gradle, it works again, but minimize my game too. i don't want to minimize my game. only want to get true or false from this boolean.

Comment: Add this to the Activity in your Manifest `<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />`. If this does not work change it to `<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />` and see what happens. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293173/use-custom-manifest-file-in-unity) post explains how to add manifest to your program. I will be back to see what happens

Comment: @Programmer nope. minimize the game again with both meta-data.

Comment: I suggest you file for a bug report from Unity Editor.