# How to use Gradle in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

Since I want to add Firebase to my Android Game I want to include Google Auth. But I have the following Problem. I need to add some Code to the build.gradle File but I cant find it in my Unity Project.

Here is the manual I found from Firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

I searched on all my Drives for build.gradle but found nothing.
Can you tell me where I find it or what do I have to do to implement the Code from the Link?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, Thanks.but I can´t upvote it :(

Comment: That's fine. You can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer which you just did.

Comment: Do you also know where to find AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Yes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293173/use-custom-manifest-file-in-unity/43293396#43293396) answer

Comment: I can´t find a Android manifest in <ProjectName>\Temp\StagingArea I don´t even have the StaginArea folder in my Project :O

Comment: Thanks! need to improve my reading skills :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use Gradle in Unity.

**1**.Go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\GradleTemplates`, then copy `mainTemplate.gradle` file to your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder.

**2**.You can then modify `mainTemplate.gradle` to be whatever you want it to be. Now, to make sure the build uses the gradle file, change the *Build System* to *"Gradle (New)"*.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

From Unity v2018.3 onwards, you can add your own custom Gradle build file by simply enabling the Custom Gradle Template property on the Player window 
(which can be accessed by File > Build Settings > Player Settings > Publishing settings).
This generates a default mainTemplate.gradle file for you, which you can edit.

It will be in the location: Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

Comment: I have an issue with this. Although the mainTemplate.gradle file in /Plugins/Android can be edited, whenever I want to build the project, Unity 2020.2.1f1 automatically resets the .gradle file to its previous state. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ CrazyBacon, you have to delete the commented line at the top of the file. That line makes the file reset on build.