# how to change default gradle.properties of Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

by default,Unity's gradle build gradle.properties only has one line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

how to add new config line to this gradle.properties?
[How to use Gradle in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711898/how-to-use-gradle-in-unity)
I know this answer, those three file can not custom `gradle.properties` file.
thank you.

Comment: This is not a duplicated question, it asks for the gradle.properties file, the linked question discuss about build.gradle, they are totally different files. Btw, I don't know how to change the default gradle.properties and I'm also looking for a way to do it.

Comment: For thoses using unity 2018.2 or newer see this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186051/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-gradle-properties-file-in-unity