# Unity Android: NoClassDefFoundError: Can't create Notifications

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, notifications, noclassdeffounderror

**Edit**

I found out, that the requirements for showing a notification consist of setting a content-title, a context-text and a small icon. The last of which I do not do. Unfortunately, I don't know, how to provide a small icon especially in unity.

**Original Question**

I'm currently trying to show a notification from a unity-instance via android. I want to show the notification, when the user enters a specific gps-area. Thus, the script should run, when the app is paused. That's why I want to use the android-functionality.

With this code, I currently try to show the notification manually:

```
    public void createNotification(){
        NotificationManagerCompat nManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(curContext);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(curContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Stuff")
                .setContentText("MoreStuff")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);



        nManager.notify(1551, builder.build());
    }
```

The context is stored in a static variable and is set, when calling the method.

The function is called in C# with:

```
PluginInstance.Call("createNotification");
```

The PluginInstance works, the function can be called, but I get the error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737566/6196568

Comment: @shingo Sorry, that did not hel.lp, however, I suspect the reason in my code, which I provide in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem: I used the [Unity Android Jar-Resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) in which I provided the `*Dependencies.xml` (Where the * presents the Name of my project). In the `*Dependenices.xml` I specified: `<androidPackage spec="androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0">` and run through the steps, provided in the Tutorial of the Resolver.

Afterwards, multiple dependencies appeared in my `/Assets/Plugin/Android`-Folder, which were successfully transferred to the app, when building it.