# Make phone call in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I used in my c# script

```
Application.OpenURL("tel:+79011111115");
```

Dialer appeared, but phone call did not occur
If it were Java, I could say that it worked like

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:+79011111115"));
```

but I need:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:+79011111115"));
```

Is there any analogy of Java's `ACTION_CALL` in C#?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/184030/dial-phone-number-from-unity.html

Comment: Yes, I did, it works perfectly well, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your Java code into *.jar* or *.aar* plugin the call it from C#. You can also use Unity's `AndroidJavaClass` and `AndroidJavaObject` API which totally eliminates the need for a Java compiled plugin.

With the `AndroidJavaClass` and `AndroidJavaObject` API, the equivalent of the **Java** code below:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:+79011111115"));
```

in **C#** is as below:

```
string phoneNum = "tel: +79011111115";

//For accessing static strings(ACTION_CALL) from android.content.Intent
AndroidJavaClass intentStaticClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
string actionCall = intentStaticClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_CALL");

//Create Uri
AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", phoneNum);

//Pass ACTION_CALL and Uri.parse to the intent
AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", actionCall, uriObject);
```

Remember you must start the Activity on the Intent to finish it and below is what it looks like in **Java**:

```
startActivity(call);
```

Below is the equivalent of that code in **C#** code to start the Activity:

```
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

try
{
    //Start Activity
    unityActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Dial number: " + e.Message);
}
```

Finally, just like in Java, you must also add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>` permission otherwise it won't work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293173/use-custom-manifest-file-and-permission-in-unity) post for how to add this Android permission to Unity.

For *Android 6.0* and above. You have to use run-time permission. [This](https://github.com/sanukin39/UniAndroidPermission) Github project should be work fine just for this.

Comment: Hi I tried your code but open skype call instead of the normal call system is it normal? is meant for for skype call? I was looking for the default system call via sim card.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for android.

```
Application.OpenURL("tel://[+1234567890]");
```