# How to switch androidmanifests in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

Im working on an app for the platforms:

- Native Android
- Pico

Therefor I have 2 different Android manifests. I've found with [MenuItems] and BuildPlayerOptions that i can create different builds on the same platform. But how can I choose the manifests, because according to my knowledge Unity automaticly searches for all manifests in the project and merges them.

Answer (score 0):

From Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html):

> For full control of the manifest, including permissions, you must
> export the Project and modify the final manifest in Android Studio.

So basically, if you want a custom manifest (without mergings, etc) you should modify the resulting manifest while compiled in Unity.

There are some different approaches for AndroidPermissions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293173/use-custom-manifest-file-and-permission-in-unity).

Comment: yea. the problem is that I have 2 different custom manifests and I want to switch between them

Comment: Switch between manifests on runtime or compile time?

Comment: compile time. and if you're suggesting statements like #if UNITY_ANDROID, that is not possible because both builds are Android.

Comment: What I recommend is the same that my answer, compile with one Manifest, then modify It on Android Studio manually.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. I have 2 allready finished manifest and with one (or 2) click in Unity I want to build a separate build for android and another for the Pico. Not after editing